# After transform onclick targets only half of the element. How to fix it?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

If you take a look on the fiddle [here](http://jsbin.com/uxehev/1/edit) (using chrome or safari), you can see an example. After applying the transforms the click only targets the lower half of my red rectangle and I need it to target the whole thing.

I am a bit lost here as if you inspect the element it occupies the whole space. I tried [wrapping into another div and setting the click on the parent](http://jsbin.com/opoqel/2/edit), but still not working.

Can I get the click to target the whole element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this: http://jsbin.com/uxehev/2/edit. I added a `translateZ` to offset the part of the element behind the "wall" (I'm pretty sure there's a better word, but I think that makes sense) after the rotation.

Relevant change below:

```
-webkit-transform:translate3d(0px, -28px, 200px) perspective(1000px) rotateX(45deg) scale(0.43068391866913125)
```

Comment: That does solve the problem! But I don't really understand what's happening here. If you set the translateZ for anything bigger than 28px it seems to work. Do you know why?

Comment: Ok nvm my previous comment, now I understand what you mean by "wall". It makes sense now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would display the visible part of the element as a pseudo element, and the clickable part as the "real" element. It would look something like this:

```
    #rect {
      width:200px;
      height:200px;
              background-color:transparent;
    }

    #rect::before {
      width:200px;
      height:200px;
      background-color:red;

      -webkit-transform:translate3d(0px, -28px, 0px) perspective(1000px) rotateX(45deg) scale(0.43068391866913125)

    }
```